# How to preserve white space in a textnode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nodes

I am intercepting a paste event and cleaning any html off of it using textNodes.

It works great, other than the fact that it reduces all whitespace to a single space, and disregards new lines completely. For example if a user were to paste

"hello       world

!"

then it would paste as "hello world !"

How can I keep the white space and new lines? Any javascript, jquery, or css tricks would be great. Here is my code:

```
iframe.contentWindow.focus()
var sel, range;
if (iframe.contentWindow.getSelection) {
    sel = iframe.contentWindow.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();}
text = window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
frag = iframe.contentDocument.createTextNode(text);
range.insertNode(frag);
```

Comment: Use `white-space : pre` or `white-space : pre-wrap` in your CSS? Or wrap the whole thing in a `<pre>` element?

Comment: try  replacing line breaks with `<br>` .

Comment: How can I go about doing that charlie? And nnnnnn, what element would I give the css to/ wrap in pre?

Comment: Whatever element you put the text into already. You could then give it a class, say `class="preserve"` and then in the stylesheet `.preserve { white-space : pre }`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it with nnnnnn's suggestion in the comments above.

```
.range_class{
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Where `.range_class` is the css class of the element the text node is being inserted into.